# Google Maps API Null Pointer Exception on GoogleMap variable

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, google-maps-android-api-2, android-fragmentactivity

Im working on an app that requires use of the Google Maps API. Ive been dealing with this problem for two days now. Im using version 2 of the API so I am using the map fragments. So, when I try to get the google map from the map fragment and assign it to my `GoogleMap googleMap` variable, it throws a null pointer exception. I guessing it is having trouble finding the fragment in which the GoogleMap object is stored in. Ive tried almost everything. I have tried to put the fragment in my main activity's xml file, using support map fragments, and programmatically adding the fragment into my xml file. Other problems have arose with those solution but the NPE was consistent among all of them. I feel like I am pretty close right now but I just need a little help to finally get it working.

Here is my GoogleMaps activity code:

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.parse.*;
import com.parse.starter.R;

import java.util.List;

public class OutbreakMap extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    double lat=50;
    double longi=50;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    Fragment fragment;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(isGooglePlayOn())    {
            setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);
        }
        //Add the map fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragment = new com.parse.starter.MapFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myfragment, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

         // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
         // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to
        // go to the settings
        if (!enabled) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Turn On Your GPS");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Please turn on your GPS to track sickness in your area!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, close
                            // current activity
                            OutbreakMap.this.finish();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();

        }
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location not found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        if(location != null)  {
            lat=location.getLatitude();
            longi=location.getLongitude();
        }

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(lat,longi))      // Sets the center of the map to lat,longi (which is 50,50 if the current location isnt found)
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        UiSettings uiSettings=googleMap.getUiSettings();
        uiSettings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Couldn't Find Location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



        ParseGeoPoint userLoc= new ParseGeoPoint(lat,longi);
        ParseQuery query= new ParseQuery("Outbreak");
        query.whereWithinMiles("location",userLoc,1);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                GetOutbreaks.getOutBreaksNearMe(googleMap,lat,longi,objects);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Recieved Outbreak Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could Not Download Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });


//        moveToPrescription();
//        moveToPrescription();
    }


    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void moveToPrescription(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Prescription.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if(googleMap==null) {
           googleMap= ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        }
        else {

        }
    }

    public boolean isGooglePlayOn() {
        int status=GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(status== ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)   {
            return true;
        }
        ((Dialog) GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status,this,10)).show();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Google Play Services cannot be found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Here is my xml file for my activity (the inner linear layout is the holder for the map fragment):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myfragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the xml file for the map fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:tag="map_fragment"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

And finally here is my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parse.starter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
    <permission
            android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:name="ParseApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ParseStarterProjectActivity"

            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Register"/>
        <activity android:name=".Login"/>
        <activity android:name=".Home"/>
        <activity android:name=".OutbreakMap"/>
        <activity android:name=".Prescription"/>
        <activity android:name=".MyPrescriptions"/>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver"></receiver>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="MY API KEY IS HERE"/>
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

</manifest>
```

Sorry, I dont have my LogCat dialog since it got erased and the phone I was testing on belongs to a friend who had to leave. But it basically said that there was a NPE at the line where it says `setUpMapIfNeeded();` and `googleMap= ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();` . Also, it is worth noting that in the AndroidManifest.xml file, it says "Cannot resolve symbol '0x00020000'" where it says `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>` at the very bottom. That doesn't stop the app from compiling and installing though. Thanks for all the help, it is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things are messed up:

1. use getSupportFragmentManager when working with FragmentActivity
2. if you want to find fragment by id, then it must exists in layout file
3. you want to add fragment in layout or in code (`fragment = new com.parse.starter.MapFragment();`) - not both
4. what is com.parse.starter.MapFragment anyway?

**Edit**: and there are things in Manifest too...

There is probably something more, but I would suggest starting from a simple project like maps samples in google play services lib.

**Edit 2**: wrong things in Manifest:

1. `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>` is unnecessary
2. `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"` should be 8 - probably the reason for `Cannot resolve symbol '0x00020000'`

You can't nest fragment inside fragment with xml. You can only instantiate nested fragment with code and use `getChildFragmentManager`.

I still don't see your MapFragment code, but if you really need this additional fragment, think of encapsulation: if Google's MapFragment is inside your MapFragment (would be good to change the name), then your MapFragment should be doing any interaction with nested fragment, not Activity.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  And 'com.parse.starter.MapFragment();' is my stupid name choice for another class that gives the inflated view of the map fragment (I put the code for that above as well). Also, I believe that I am putting in the fragment only programmatically at the moment.  I am taking it from 'com.parse.starter.MapFragment();' and placing it in the inner linear layout of my activity's layout xml file. Please do correct me if I am wrong about that though. And also, what is wrong in my Android Manifest?

Answer (score -1):

Use `getSupportFragmentManager` when working with `FragmentActivity`

if you want to find fragment by id, then it must exists in layout file you want to add fragment in layout 
or in code 
`(fragment = new com.parse.starter.MapFragment();)`

Note: Must not use both

what is com.parse.starter.MapFragment anyway?